# iPhone locking rotation to portrait view

Tags: iphone, rotation

I know this has been asked before and I actually searched through the questions to make sure I was doing things correctly. My app needs to maintain portrait orientation so I want to disable it from rotating into landscape.

In the summary I have supported device orientations of portrait and upside down only. 
In viewcontroller I have:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

{
    return NO;
    }

I have 6 other viewcontrollers, in each of them I have the following:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

But when I test the app on my provisioned iPhone, it rotates. Grrrr. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

It's the same in the simulator.

Comment: what is your rootViewController? Does these methods get called at all? Try with some logging..

Comment: What is the structure of your app? UITabBarController with UINavigationController objects? Please tell us more.

Comment: It worked, this is embarrassing but I was working on the wrong version... : P